# Pandas dropping dup contains string with conditions

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I want to drop duplicates that contains some specific strings.
For example, I have the following df:

```
Name   Day   Value
111    1       z
111    2       z
111    3       z
111    4       a
111    5       a
222    1       y
222    2       y
222    3       b
222    4       b
333    1       c
333    2       c
333    3       c
333    4       x
333    5       x
```

The condition is this:

For any Name with values [x,y,z] we keep last

For any Name with values [a,b,c] we keep first

```
Name   Day   Value
111    3       z
111    4       a
222    2       y
222    3       b
333    1       c
333    5       x
```

I tried the drop_duplicates keep last/first method but I'm not sure how to implement the conditions in there.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We split original df to two , then do `drop_duplicates` separately

```
s=df.loc[df.Value.isin(['x','y','z']),:].drop_duplicates(['Name','Value'],keep='last')
v=df.loc[df.Value.isin(['a','b','c']),:].drop_duplicates(['Name','Value'],keep='first')

pd.concat([s,v]).sort_index()
Out[53]: 
    Name  Day Value
2    111    3     z
3    111    4     a
6    222    2     y
7    222    3     b
9    333    1     c
13   333    5     x
```